# Identify database records that point to each other

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a database of user records and each time the user takes an action, a record is stored. Each action has a "parent" action in the database, and has a column that points to the id of that parent action. This creates a chain of all the user's actions:

```
id  |  action  |  parent_id
----+----------+------------
1   |  create  |
2   |  update  |  1
3   |  update  |  2
```

Let's say through some mistake, two records ended up pointing at each other, where the `parent_id` of each is the `id` of the other:

```
id  |  action  |  parent_id
----+----------+------------
1   |  create  |
2   |  update  |  3
3   |  update  |  2
```

How can I construct a SQL command to identify rows that point to one another (ids `2` and `3`)? I don't even know where to start. Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you asking how to find cycles in a graph?  Or are you just interested in this simple case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option using `exists`:

```
select * 
from yourtable t1
where exists (
  select 1
  from yourtable t2
  where t1.id = t2.parent_id and t2.id = t1.parent_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option using a self-join:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM mytable t1
INNER JOIN mytable t2 
    ON  t1.parent_id = t2.id 
    AND t1.id = t2.parent_id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bz7JfojNcFjkSr8hXYSmYD/0)**:

```
| id  | action | parent_id |
| --- | ------ | --------- |
| 3   | update | 2         |
| 2   | update | 3         |
```